# Intercept a class instance with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm trying to implement interceptor on an instantiated class, but no methods are intercepted in this case.
All works fine with normally registered components, `Castle Windsor` intercepts all the methods of my component.

I know that by design `Castle Windsor` cannot intercept a registered instantiated class, but I was saw this post and tried to implement it with no luck:
[Castle Windsor Cannot Intercept Component Registered For A Class Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162769/castle-windsor-cannot-intercept-component-registered-for-a-class-instance)

This is my current implementation :

My Factory Interface :

```cs
public interface ITransferProtocolFactory
{
    ITransferProtocol GetTransferProtocol(string transferProtocolName);
}
```

Registration of the factory:

```cs
IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For<ITransferProtocolFactory>().AsFactory(new NamedTypeFactory()));
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For<NamedTypeFactory, ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>());
```

Override of the `GetComponentName` method :

```cs
public class NamedTypeFactory : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector 
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        string componentName = null;
        if (arguments != null && arguments.Length > 0)
        {
            componentName = arguments[0] as string;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(componentName))
            componentName = base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
        return componentName;
    }
}
```

Registering my interceptor :

```cs
public static class InterceptorsRegistrar
{
    public static void Initialize(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.ComponentRegistered += Kernel_ComponentRegistered;
    }

    private static void Kernel_ComponentRegistered(string key, IHandler handler)
    {
        if (typeof(ITransferProtocol).IsAssignableFrom(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation) &&  
                !typeof(IProxyTransferUserAction).IsAssignableFrom(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation))
        {
            handler.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add
                (new InterceptorReference(typeof(TransferUserActionInterceptor)));
        }
    }
}

InterceptorsRegistrar.Initialize(IocManager.IocContainer.Kernel);
```

Creation of instance and registration :

```cs
public void CreateAndInjectMachineProtocol(MachineForAgentDto machine)
{
    var machineProtocol = (ITransferProtocol)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Agent.Protocols." + Enum.GetName(typeof(eCommunicationType), machine.CommunicationType)));

    _iocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For<ITransferProtocol>().Instance(machineProtocol).Named(nameof(ITransferProtocol) + machine.Id.ToString()).LifestyleSingleton());
}
```

The Interceptor :

```cs
public class TransferUserActionInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IMachineManager _machineManager;

    public TransferUserActionInterceptor(IMachineManager machineManager)
    {
        _machineManager = machineManager;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

And finally the resolver of the component through the factory:

```cs
private ITransferProtocol GetMachineProtocol(long machineId)
{
    return _transferProtocolFactory.GetTransferProtocol(nameof(ITransferProtocol) + machineId.ToString());
}
```

The Interception is not working in this case because of the design limitation of `Castle Windsor`.

I have trid to implement this solution [Castle Windsor Cannot Intercept Component Registered For A Class Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162769/castle-windsor-cannot-intercept-component-registered-for-a-class-instance) but the interception continue not to working (maybe I have implemented it wrong).

So here are my 2 questions :

How can I implement the stackoverflow post solution on top of my current code to let methods of the `ITransferProtocol` injected instance be intercepted?

Do you have another solution that the stackoverflow post suggest?

Thanks for your help.